# Receive [Not Found] error in Alpine Docker Container although it certainly exists

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, alpine-linux

When running the alpine docker container and trying to build, I get such error message.

```
/bin/sh: /etc/init.d/postgresql: not found
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.5

MAINTAINER hoge

ENV LANG en_US.utf8

ENV PHX_PORT 4000
ENV PHX_DBNAME hoge_db

COPY release.tar.gz /

RUN echo 'http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing' >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .base_deps build-base openssl-dev zlib-dev libxml2-dev wget gnupg ca-certificates && \
    apk add --no-cache readline-dev glib-lang libssl1.0 postgresql postgresql-client && \
    apk add --update binutils && \
    apk add --no-cache sudo && \
    apk --purge del .base_deps && \
    tar -xzf ./release.tar.gz && \
    echo "postgres ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/postgres && \
    chmod 600 /etc/sudoers.d/postgres && \
    sync && \
    /etc/init.d/postgresql setup && \
    /etc/init.d/postgresql start && \
    readelf -l /etc/init.d/postgresql | grep "program interpreter" && \
    psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE $PHX_DBNAME WITH ENCODING 'UTF8' OWNER=postgres TEMPLATE = template0;"


VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data

ENTRYPOINT ["psql", "-U", "postgres"]

EXPOSE 5432
```

`/etc/init.d/postgresql` is certainly exists.
I surely confirmed that is exist by actually entering the container.
How should I modify?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `openrc` to your list of `apk add` commands.

Found the solution on a [github issue](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/183) of the same, after inspecting the `/etc/init.d/postgresql` file and seeing the shebang line reference openrc